# Editing a PDF in UIDocumentInteractionController and saving..?

Tags: ios, pdf

I've got an 'interactive PDF' that I need to be able to edit and save in an iOS app and I'm looking at how to achieve it. It's got text boxes and radio buttons which I can interact with in the `UIDocumentInteractionController` preview (or `QLPreviewController`) but there doesn't seem to be a way to save those changes to the file that was loaded and if I share the live and edited file to my mac via AirDrop it doesn't send the changes, rather it seems just the original file.

I don't really know anything about interactive PDFs so not sure how added text would normally be saved. I've found that the 'Files' app (added in iOS 11) actually saves the edits you make, so that's basically what I want to be able to do.

At the end of the day I just need a way to be able to interact with a PDF in my app and save the changes. Do I maybe need to use a custom PDF viewer rather than trying to piggy back off the standard iOS file previewer functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this library solves my problem: https://github.com/derekblair/ILPDFKit

It lets you edit a PDF, access and set individual fields and save out as a static PDF.